# AWK subtract 3rd with 1st line, 6th with 4th etc recursively, and then average out

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, awk

I have a file with a list of numbers, like this

```
4.90889
4.92681
4.99236
5.29358
5.3115
5.37706
5.9354
5.95332
6.01888
```

I need to subtract the third number with the first, then procede with the next 3 line block recursively, save the results and average them out. I know how to make an average with awk but I'm lost on the first operation.

Using the numbers above it would be:

```
4.99236 - 4.90889 = 0.08347
5.37706 - 5.29358 = 0.08348
6.01888 - 5.9354 = 0.08348

(0.08347 + 0.08348 + 0.08348)/3 = 0,0834766666667
```

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of modulo arithmetic:

```
awk '
  FNR%3 == 1 {last = $0} 
  FNR%3 == 0 {sum += $0 - last; n++} 
  END {print (n > 0 ? sum/n : 0)}
' file
```